# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" popup Visual Studio Desktop

Tags: c++, error-handling, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio Desktop and I am having a little problem. Whenver I try to paste something or simply press "Enter", an error message saying "object reference not set to an instance of an object" appears (this is not from compiling, its just an error message that visual studio pops up). Does anyone know what this means? The error is not code related from what I can see...

Comment: You're going to have to show the code I believe.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough info to answer this, but there *are* hundreds of immediate hits on Google for `visual studio "object reference not set to an instance of an object"`. I'd start there. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158354/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error-on-visual-studio-2013) is very similar, though not resolved it may be applicable. There is also the [Update 1 Patch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2014/01/21/visual-studio-update-1-is-available.aspx) which mentions this and may also address your issue. Best of luck.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a C++ error. C++/CLI perhaps.

Comment: if you resolved the solution you should post the answer here. This is a site that everybody should benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem seems to have resolved itself, but I am not 100% sure how. I think it had to do  with a Virtual Void problem that I found in my code, where I had a virtual void being overwritten by the wrong sub class. I cannot garuantee that this was the solution to the problem though.